# C/C++: Conversion of char[] to int fails, unsigned char[] to int works, why?

Tags: c++, c, serialization, file-io, type-conversion

I haven't found a question answering this exact behaviour, and somehow I just don't understand what is going on:

I read the contents of a Windows Bitmap File (bmp) into a array and use this array later to extract required information:

```
char biHeader[40];
// ...
source.read(biHeader,40);
// ...
int biHeight = biHeader[8] | (biHeader[9] << 8) | (biHeader[10] << 16) | (biHeader[11] << 24);
```

After this, `biHeight` shows as `-112` which is totally wrong because it should be `400`.
So, I took a look at a hexdump of the file. The contents read are:

```
90 01 00 00
```

Changing the byte order to big endian gives `0x190` which is `400` in decimal, as expected.

If I change above code to:

```
unsigned char biHeader[40];
// ...
source.read((char*)biHeader,40);
// ...
int biHeight = ... (same as before)
```

... then I get the expected value. What is going on here?

And: How would you read this data?

Comment: One more thing: I really NEED to convert to int and NOT unsigned int because the value could be negative!

Comment: usually BITMAPINFOHEADER is read as a struct, where biHeight is a LONG on windows platform at least

Comment: I decided to not read it as a struct because there are multiple versions of this header (with different fields towards the end).

As a LONG? According to the file format definition, this is wrong.
Or, to be more specific: biHeight is composed of 4 bytes (and not more; as LONG could be 8 bytes)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As a signed 8-bit two's complement integer, `0x90` is `-112`. When that is converted to `int` for the `|`, its value is preserved. Since all bits from the seventh on are set if the representation is two's complement, a bitwise or with values shifted left by at least eight bits doesn't change the value anymore.

As an unsigned 8-bit integer, the value of `0x90` is 144, a positive number with no bits beyond the `2^7` bit set. Then, a bitwise or with `biHeader[9] << 8` changes the value to the desired `144 + 256 = 400`.

When working with bitwise operators, (almost) always use unsigned types, signed types often lead to unpleasant surprises (and undefined behaviour if the shift result is out of range or a negative integer is shifted left).

Comment: Ah, ok, thank you. That totally makes sense. So I keep reading it into a unsigned char[].

Comment: Note that the code contains `biHeader[11] << 24`, which implicitly converts `biHeader[11]` to an int and shifts it 24 bits. So the C standard does not define the behavior when `biHeader[11]` is 128 or more and `int` is 32 bits. Since this code wants an `int` result, it requires either a guarantee from the compiler about the behavior or special handling for this case or a guarantee that `biHeader[11]` will never be 128 or greater.

Comment: I see, my "main problem" is, that the compiler tries to interpret the values. It's probably better to sort (little endian to big endian) the values inside the array and then use a int pointer to the correct location in memory, right?

Comment: @DanielOertwig I don't think so. Using an `int*` may have alignment problems, and some platforms are big-endian, others little-endian. It is IMO better to use `unsigned int`s for shifting (or `uint32_t`/`uint_least32_t` to be sure that shifting an 8-bit value by 24 places doesn't overflow). Like `(uint32_t)biHeader[8] | ((uint32_t)biHeader[9] << 8) | ...`. Now the problem remains that if the value is outside `int` range [usually if and only if the `2^7` bit in `biHeader[11]` is set], the conversion to `int` is implementation-defined. It would be nice if the type of `biHeight` could be unsigned

Comment: If it has to be `int`, the typical conversion from `unsigned int` to `int` is just a reinterpretation of the bits, so that would be fine (but not totally portable).

Comment: The final result has to be int (because it IS a signed number in twos complement) but my "buffer" (i.e. `biHeader`) could be of any type that allows me to correct the endianess (so there is `signed char` and `unsigned char` left). So I could use a unsigned char array for biHeight and then use the shift operators directly (without explicit conversion to uin32_t) because unsigned char will be promoted to unsigned int by the compiler?

Comment: @DanielOertwig No, `unsigned char` will be promoted to `int` [on normal platforms where `CHAR_BIT == 8`], so you have the `biHeader[11]` problem (the others need not be cast, those shifts can't overflow `int`). You could also use a `union type_pun { int height; unsigned char bits[4]; }` to type-pun (that's unambiguously allowed as of TC3 to C99, iirc) if `sizeof(int) == 4`. (If `sizeof(int) < 4` you will have a problem anyway, if it's larger, the plain shift works; if you want it portable, use fixed-size types `uint8_t` and `int32_t`.)